# image changing to another image changing in pygame

Tags: image, python-3.x, pygame

i made a program in pygame ware a mine turtle runs in a sqare but when you click in the box he explodes but when i change the image to an explodtion it shows th mineturtle first
here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys, time
    from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 40 # frames per second setting
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

print("if you click the mine tutle box he will explode")

cat = pygame.image.load("mineturtle.PNG")
catx = 10
caty = 10
direction = 'right'
s=15
while True: # the main game loop
DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE) 
if direction == 'right':
    catx += s
    if catx == 280:
        direction = 'down'
elif direction == 'down':
    caty += s
    if caty == 220:
        direction = 'left'
elif direction == 'left':
    catx -= s
    if catx == 10:
        direction = 'up'
elif direction == 'up':
    caty -= s
    if caty == 10:
        direction = 'right'
DISPLAYSURF.blit(cat, (catx, caty))

for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         b = pygame.image.load("b.png")
         time.sleep(2)
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()
     if event.type == QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

i already have all of the files in the same loaction but when i did the image swich id didn't work! plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just did this

```
import pygame, sys, time
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()

FPS = 40 # frames per second setting
fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set up the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Animation')

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

print("if you click the mine tutle box he will explode")

cat = pygame.image.load("mineturtle.PNG")
catx = 10
caty = 10`enter code here`
direction = 'right'
s=15
explodetick=0
move=True
while True: # the main game loop
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(WHITE)
    #for event in pygame.event.get():
    #     
      if explodetick>0:
          explodetick+=1
      if explodetick==81: 
         pygame.quit()
 if move:
    if direction == 'right':
        catx += s
        if catx == 280:
            direction = 'down'
    elif direction == 'down':
        caty += s
        if caty == 220:
            direction = 'left'
    elif direction == 'left':
        catx -= s
        if catx == 10:
            direction = 'up'
    elif direction == 'up':
        caty -= s
        if caty == 10:
            direction = 'right'
DISPLAYSURF.blit(cat, (catx, caty))

for event in pygame.event.get():
     if event.type == QUIT:
         pygame.quit()
         sys.exit()
     if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         cat = pygame.image.load("b.png")
         pygame.display.update()
         explodetick=1
         move=False

pygame.display.update()
fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Answer (score 1):

To show changes on screen you need to call pygame.display.update(). When you call sleep and exit, it does not update the screen, and no changes are seen.
time.

EDIT:

If you wish to show a new image for 2 seconds and then close the program, you should use pygame.time module. Have a variable that will store the time since the last click. You add the result of tick(). When the value will be high enough, you can exit pygame.

This will not freeze the window, and you will be able to see the changes.